# How can I see a summary of all my "faction-wide" bonuses?

Tags: three-kingdoms-total-war

In *Total War: Three Kingdoms*, lots of reforms, character abilities, and buildings that provide small, usually stackable factionn-wide bonuses.

Is there a way to see all of the ones that currently apply to your faction?

For example, if I'm building a bunch of these in my least "profitable" commanderies to try to get to 0% redeployment cost, is there a status screen that'll show me my exact curreent combined redeployment cost modifier from buildings and reforms?

[image: Training Camp (tier 3): provides -5% redeployment cost (faction-wide)]